# How to avoid appending elements to DOM in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

My function is like below. Consider for high performance, how can I avoid to add text in a loop structure in html? Please advise. Thank you so much.

```
function  createDiv (array) {
    var i;
    var target = document.getElementById("container");
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {       
        target.appendChild("<div>" + array[i] + "</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a template engine like Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Also this question may be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add these to a [*document fragment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment), and append that fragment once finished:

```
var target = document.getElementById("container");

function createDiv (array) {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {       
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = array[i];
        fragment.appendChild(div);
    }
    target.appendChild(fragment);
 }
```

This approach mutates the DOM only once. Note also, the `#container` lookup should probably happen before calling this method, to avoid unnecessary work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should change div.innerHTML = array[i] ?

Comment: @Sleepyhead Yes. My apologies for that oversight.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an element outside the loop, and inside the loop append to the element (not touching the DOM).
Then after the loop finishes, append the new object to the html.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string in the loop and then inject the string as an element once after the loop has finished:

```
function  createDiv (array) {
    var result = "";
    var target = document.getElementById("container");
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {       
        result += "<div>" + array[i] + "</div>";
    }
    target.appendChild(result);
 }
```